# How to remove nested attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JSON file: http://danish-regional-data.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/danish_regional_data.json

How do I remove all the attribues `within_5_km`, `within_10_km`, `within_25_km`, `within_50_km`, `within_100_km` for all postcodes?

I have read this question: [Remove a JSON attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219630/remove-a-json-attributes)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON("post.json", function(data) {

    var pc = data.postalcodes;
    for (var id in pc) {
       if(pc.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
          for(var attr in pc[id]) {
             if(pc[id].hasOwnProperty(attr) && attr.indexOf('within_') === 0) {
               delete pc[id][attr];
             }
          }
       }
    }

    $("#json").html(pc);

    });

});
```

Comment: Well, you need to recursively loop over your JSON object, searching for those attributes, and delete them if/when they're found, per the answer in your linked question.

Comment: **Warning** 12MB `.json` file in the question

Comment: If you're looking to do this after a JSON call to get the data it would be redundant as you'd have had to download them all first to remove them.

Comment: @Lübnah - Can you show how to do that? Because in the linked question there is no loop or search :/

Comment: @Lübnah, actually there is no such thing as JSON object. JSON is used as a representation of an object of specified type.

Comment: @JaroslawWaliszko Okay, that's a bit pedantic, but yes that's technically correct. JSON == JavaScript Object Notation. So, what I /meant/ was the object the OP has expressed in JSON. Happy now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the json url you provided and open the Firebug console. Then drop in the folloing code and execute it:

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('pre');
for(i=0; i < p.length; i++) {

  var data = JSON.parse(p[i].innerHTML);
  var pc = data.postalcodes;

  // this is the code i gave you... the previous is jsut to pull it out of the page
  // in Firebug - this works for me

  for (var id in pc) {
     if(pc.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
        for(var attr in pc[id]) {
          if(pc[id].hasOwnProperty(attr) && attr.indexOf('within_') === 0) {
             console.log('Deleting postalcodes.'+id+'.'+attr);
             delete pc[id][attr];
           }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

---

```
// assume data is the complete json

var pc = data.postalcodes;
for (var id in pc) {
   if(pc.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      for(var attr in pc[id]) {
         if(pc[id].hasOwnProperty(attr) && attr.indexOf('within_') === 0) {
           delete pc[id][attr];
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Of course, this would be after OP converted the JSON string into an actual object

Comment: I have tried your solution, but it does not work. I have updated my question with my code.

Comment: Absolutely no need for `hasOwnProperty`

Comment: @Lübnah: Well i assumed he was already fine with the parsing. The question didnt ask how to convert a json string to a js object it was about nested iteration.

Comment: @Railsbeginner: Try `$("#json").text(JSON.stringify(data));` instead

Comment: @Rails beginner: Did you get any errors? See my update for a test.

Comment: @Bergi: True... force of habit (re: hasOwnProperty).

Comment: @prodigitalson - I see it deletes in the console, how do I copy/get the new code?

Comment: @Railsbeginner, when you delete those attributes in your loop you are augmenting the single copy of you **data** object. Within the loop you are simply creating references to parts of the **data** object. After the loop you can access the new version by referencing the same **data** object

Comment: @cbayram - I see console.dir(data); and then I can just copy the data in the console :)

Answer (score 3):

In ES2016 you can use [destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to pick the fields you want for the subset object.

```
//ES6 subset of an object by specific fields
var object_private = {name: "alex", age: 25, password: 123};
var {name,age} = object_private, object_public = {name,age}


//method 2 using literals
let object_public = (({name,age})=>({name,age}))(object_private);


//use map if array of objects
    users_array.map(u=>u.id)
```

Comment: Dropping a chunk of code isn't usually very helpful. Can you explain *why* this should work?

Answer (score 1):

JSON truncated:

```
var data = {"postalcodes":
{"800":{"id":"800","name":"H\u00f8je Taastrup","region_ids":["1084"],"region_names":["Hovedstaden"],"commune_ids":["169"],"commune_names":["H\u00f8je-Taastrup"],"lat":"55.66713","lng":"12.27888", "within_5_km":["800","2620","2630","2633"],"within_10_km":["800","2600","2605","2620"]},
"900":{"id":"900","name":"K\u00f8benhavn C","region_ids":["1084"],"region_names":["Hovedstaden"],"commune_ids":["101"],"commune_names":["K\u00f8benhavns"],"lat":"55.68258093401054","lng":"12.603657245635986","within_5_km":["900","999"]},
"1417":{"commune_id":"390","region_id":"1085"}}};
var pc = data.postalcodes;
for (var id in pc) {
    var entry = pc[id];
    for(var attr in entry) {
        if(attr.indexOf('within_') === 0) {
            delete entry[attr];
        }
    }
}
console.dir(data); // your data object has been augmented at this point
```

you can also use regular expression

```
var data = {"postalcodes":
{"800":{"id":"800","name":"H\u00f8je Taastrup","region_ids":["1084"],"region_names":["Hovedstaden"],"commune_ids":["169"],"commune_names":["H\u00f8je-Taastrup"],"lat":"55.66713","lng":"12.27888", "within_5_km":["800","2620","2630","2633"],"within_10_km":["800","2600","2605","2620"]},
"900":{"id":"900","name":"K\u00f8benhavn C","region_ids":["1084"],"region_names":["Hovedstaden"],"commune_ids":["101"],"commune_names":["K\u00f8benhavns"],"lat":"55.68258093401054","lng":"12.603657245635986","within_5_km":["900","999"]},
"1417":{"commune_id":"390","region_id":"1085"}}};
var regexp = new RegExp("^within_", "i");   // case insensitive regex matching strings starting with within_
var pc = data.postalcodes;
for (var id in pc) {
    var entry = pc[id];
    for(var attr in entry) {
        if(regexp.test(attr)) {
            delete entry[attr];
        }
    }
}
console.dir(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written an npm module [unset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unset) which exactly does this. You specify json paths similar to the [json-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-path) module until the leaf attribute that you want to remove.

```
let unset = require('unset');
let object = {a: { b: [ {x: 1}, {x: [{ e: 2} ]}]}};
let newObject = unset(object, ['/a/b[*]/x']);
```

Multiple paths are supported in the second argument

Answer (score 0):

well you can do this:

```
var postalcodes = YOUR JSON;

for(var code in postalcodes)
{
 delete postalcodes[code].within_5_km;
 .
 .
 .
}
```

you will probably want to check if the code contains your properties...