# remove a key from a object which is inside an object

Tags: javascript, object

I need to remove vegetables from this object

```
 "shop":
     {
     "items":
       {
          "fruits" : [],
         "vegetables" :[]
       }
    } 
  }
```

i tried deleting by "delete shop.items.fuits"... but it didnot work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove nested attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234301/how-to-remove-nested-attributes)

Comment: If the code in the question is correct you are missing quotes around the vegetable property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working...

```js
const o = { a: { b: { c: [], d: 4 } } }
delete o.a.b.c

console.log(o)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```