# how to remove json object key and value.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

I have a json object as shown below. where i want to delete the "otherIndustry" entry and its value by using below code which doesn't worked.

```
var updatedjsonobj = delete myjsonobj['otherIndustry'];
```

How to remove Json object specific key and its value.
Below is my example json object where i want to remove "otherIndustry" key and its value.

```
var myjsonobj =  {
      "employeeid": "160915848",
      "firstName": "tet",
      "lastName": "test",
      "email": "test@email.com",
      "country": "Brasil",
      "currentIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "otherIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "currentOrganization": "test",
      "salary": "1234567"
    };
delete myjsonobj ['otherIndustry'];
console.log(myjsonobj);
```

where the log still prints the same object without removing 'otherIndustry' entry from the object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove key-value pair from JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24770887/remove-key-value-pair-from-json-object)

Comment: Your code should work, can you create a MVCE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: delete myObj.other.key1; [As shown in this example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219630/remove-a-json-attribute/1219633#1219633)

Comment: *which doesn't worked* What was the result? can you please explain?

Comment: Nope @Alexandru-IonutMihai, actually my code is 
`var myjsonobj ={  "employeeid": "160915848",
  "firstName": "tet",
  "lastName": "test",
  "email": "test@email.com",
  "country": "Brasil",
  "currentIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "otherIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "currentOrganization": "test",
  "salary": "1234567"
};  delete myjsonobj ['otherIndustry'];      console.log(myjsonobj );` still prints the same object. :(

Comment: @krishkr, and what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @krishkr, prints `typeof myjsonobj` and tell me what you've received.

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai console.log(typeof myjsonobj); prints "string" :( how can i convert it to json before json delete method usage. ?

Comment: @krishkr, use this: `myjsonobj=JSON.parse(myjsonobj); delete myjsonobj['otherIndustry']`

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai thanks a lot that works, can you help me how to get back to the string after json parse which is needed to my AJAX call.

Comment: Yes, just use `myjsonobj=JSON.stringify(myjsonobj)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove a property from a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208105/how-do-i-remove-a-property-from-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 123, accepted):

`delete` operator is used to `remove` an object `property`.

`delete` operator **does not** returns the new object, only returns a `boolean`:  **true** or **false**.

In the other hand, after interpreter executes `var updatedjsonobj = delete myjsonobj['otherIndustry'];` , `updatedjsonobj` variable will store a `boolean`
value.

> How to remove Json object specific key and its value ?

You just need to know the property name in order to delete it from the object's properties.

```
delete myjsonobj['otherIndustry'];
```

```js
let myjsonobj = {
  "employeeid": "160915848",
  "firstName": "tet",
  "lastName": "test",
  "email": "test@email.com",
  "country": "Brasil",
  "currentIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "otherIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "currentOrganization": "test",
  "salary": "1234567"
}
delete myjsonobj['otherIndustry'];
console.log(myjsonobj);
```

If you want to remove a `key` when you know the value you can use `Object.keys` function which returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties.

```js
let value="test";
let myjsonobj = {
      "employeeid": "160915848",
      "firstName": "tet",
      "lastName": "test",
      "email": "test@email.com",
      "country": "Brasil",
      "currentIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "otherIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
      "currentOrganization": "test",
      "salary": "1234567"
}
Object.keys(myjsonobj).forEach(function(key){
  if (myjsonobj[key] === value) {
    delete myjsonobj[key];
  }
});
console.log(myjsonobj);
```

Comment: So irrespective of return value, will the `key:value` be deleted from object, as per OP's code?

Comment: you can also use dot notation: `delete myjsonobj.otherIndustry;`

Answer (score 18):

There are several ways to do this, lets see them one by one:

1. **delete** method: The most common way

```js
const myObject = {
    "employeeid": "160915848",
    "firstName": "tet",
    "lastName": "test",
    "email": "test@email.com",
    "country": "Brasil",
    "currentIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "otherIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "currentOrganization": "test",
    "salary": "1234567"
};

delete myObject['currentIndustry'];
// OR delete myObject.currentIndustry;
  
console.log(myObject);
```

2. By making key value **undefined**: Alternate & a faster way:

```js
let myObject = {
    "employeeid": "160915848",
    "firstName": "tet",
    "lastName": "test",
    "email": "test@email.com",
    "country": "Brasil",
    "currentIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "otherIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "currentOrganization": "test",
    "salary": "1234567"
  };

myObject.currentIndustry = undefined;
myObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject));

console.log(myObject);
```

3. With es6 **spread** Operator:

```js
const myObject = {
    "employeeid": "160915848",
    "firstName": "tet",
    "lastName": "test",
    "email": "test@email.com",
    "country": "Brasil",
    "currentIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "otherIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
    "currentOrganization": "test",
    "salary": "1234567"
};


const {currentIndustry, ...filteredObject} = myObject;
console.log(filteredObject);
```

Or if you can use **omit()** of **underscore** js library:

```
const filteredObject = _.omit(currentIndustry, 'myObject');
console.log(filteredObject);
```

**When to use what??**

If you don't wanna create a new filtered object, simply go for either option 1 or 2. Make sure you define your object with **let** while going with the second option as we are overriding the values. Or else you can use any of them.

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 8):

Follow this, it can be like what you are looking:

```js
var obj = {
    Objone: 'one',
    Objtwo: 'two'
};

var key = "Objone";
delete obj[key];
console.log(obj); // prints { "objtwo": two}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one more example. (check the **[reference](https://codeburst.io/use-es2015-object-rest-operator-to-omit-properties-38a3ecffe90)**)

```js
const myObject = {
  "employeeid": "160915848",
  "firstName": "tet",
  "lastName": "test",
  "email": "test@email.com",
  "country": "Brasil",
  "currentIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "otherIndustry": "aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
  "currentOrganization": "test",
  "salary": "1234567"
};
const {otherIndustry, ...otherIndustry2} = myObject;
console.log(otherIndustry2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function omit(obj, key) {
    const {[key]:ignore, ...rest} = obj;
    return rest;
}
```

You can use ES6 spread operators like this. And to remove your key simply call

```
const newJson = omit(myjsonobj, "otherIndustry");
```

Its always better if you maintain pure function when you deal with `type=object` in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with trying to delete a returned JSON object and found that it was actually a string. If you JSON.parse() before deleting you can be sure your key will get deleted.

```
let obj;
console.log(this.getBody()); // {"AED":3.6729,"AZN":1.69805,"BRL":4.0851}
obj = this.getBody();
delete obj["BRL"];
console.log(obj) // {"AED":3.6729,"AZN":1.69805,"BRL":4.0851}
obj = JSON.parse(this.getBody());
delete obj["BRL"];
console.log(obj) // {"AED":3.6729,"AZN":1.69805}
```